# Probability density function of a random variable

Tags: probability

How to find a Probability Density/Mass Function for a random variable without assuming it follows a predetermined distribution, say, Normal or Poisson etc,. Lets say i have two hours of data of vehicle arrives at a specific point and i want to know what kind of distribution it has? Please help me understand this. Thank You, Guys.

Answer (score 0):

Usual method to solve this problem is step by step trial and error method. Your data may or may not fit for a known distribution. You may easily calculate mean, median, mood, variance, etc. for your data set. Now try to guess which distribution may be fit for your data. Apply goodness of fit tests to understand if the distribution is fit for your data. If not then try with some other distribution. That's all.